# Error importing and using RecyclerView

Tags: android, import, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when creating a simple RecyclerView
When I import what is necessary to use it, I always get the same error message.

In the main class i have the following imports:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

and in then adapter class, the followings:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

I want to emphasize that I have imported `import android.view.View;` by the need of the ViewHolder *(View view = mInflater.inflate ...)*

Well, I always get an error with the following message:

[image]

Something that I find very curious is also that in the ViewHolder of the adapter, with a TextView, the same thing happens to me:

[image]

In my build.gradle file, these are my imports:

[image]

I am using Android Studio 3.1.2

I appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your view like

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
```

Your problem will be solved.

But if you compile your app with API 26, you don't even need to cast, and your existing code will work. :) like

In older versions:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
```

In AS3.0 with sdk 26:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
```